# Colorize each part of QR code such as timing pattern and format information

Tags: qr-code

For educational purpose, I'd like to colorize each element of QR code. For example, you may take a look at this URL page.

https://www.qr-code-generator.com/qr-code-marketing/qr-codes-basics/

This page contains colorized image of each part of QR code such as Positioning markings, Timing pattern, and Format information. I'd like to similar analysis, but with my own QR code. Does any one know which programming tool do I have to use to colorize each element of QR code?